# How to put license agreement in spec file, RPM

Tags: fedora, rpm

I am using Fedora 10 linux. I want to put license agreement for my spec file. Actually I have created rpm for my application. So my application gets installed perfectly without asking for license agreement. I want whenever i will install RPM then i should get license and if i agree then only installation should proceed. How to achieve this type of functionality in my RPM.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.

rpm is designed around batch, non-interactive operation.

If you should use a EULA, then present it in the first application run by each user.

Comment: Hi I have installed jdk1.6 rpm in my computer in fedora linux. there I have to accept terms and condition to make my software installable on my computer

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Adding User License Agreement in Solaris package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377074/adding-user-license-agreement-in-solaris-package)
Take the idea which i have used for Solaris pacakge.
Hope it helps.